# CORS Problem with private third party api on VUEJS app

Tags: api, vue.js, proxy

I know lot of articles and QnAs about CORS and how to solve it, but when it comes private third party api is overwhelming, I've tried to solve this for quite a while and didn't work, I have tried many ways, one of them are configuring **devServer proxy** on the vue.config.js, my third party api server runs on http://localhost:8080 and my vue-app runs on http://localhost:3000

```
axios
                .post("patient/request/" + this.$store.state.token, {
                    patients: [
                        {
                            index: "1",
                            patientIdentifier: {
                                domain: "mdat",
                                name: "pat_id",
                                id: this.id,
                                type: "localIdentifier",
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.data.patients.length === 0) {
                        this.showAlert(
                            this.$t("requestPSNbyID.not_found"),
                            "error"
                        );
                    } else {
                        this.dataLoad = response.data.patients[0].patient;
                        console.log(this.dataLoad);
                        this.rpsn = true;
                    }
                    this.$store.dispatch("getToken", this.payload);
                    //state.mdatID = response.data.patients[0].targetId;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    this.errorHandler(error);
                });
```

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: "http://localhost:8080",
  }
}
```

but I get error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/ths/rest/sessions' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy
```

any other solution?

Comment: Can you please add the axios or fetch request you use for your API call?

Comment: yesss.....@Gabe

Comment: What is the base url you are using for Axios? `http://localhost:3000`?

Comment: Yeah, the vue app runs ron localhost:3000 @Gabe

Comment: Yes, but do you actually call the api also on localhost port 3000? Looks like you are calling it on port 8080. So you are not using the proxy.

Comment: no, my api server runs on localhost:8080, 3000 is my frontend vue app, that's why I set the proxy into 8080, or do I understand in the wrong way ? @Gabe

Comment: You need to connect to the proxy on localhost:3000, which redirects to port 8080. This way the browser sees the same origin for the frontend and the api server. I think my answer below will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do the following. Set the axios base url to http://localhost:3000/api.

`axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api';`

See: [Axios config defaults](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults)

Then you need to change your proxy settings in your vue.config.js to:

```
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://localhost:8080',
    pathRewrite: { '^/api': '' },
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
  },
},
```

See: [devServer.proxy docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy)

What this does is that it will send all Axios request to the localhost proxy at /api. Since the api server on 8080 does not have the /api prefix, the proxy will remove the '/api' by rewriting the path. The api server will receive the correct request. The browser will no longer be complaining about cross origins, because both the Vue frontend and backend have the same http://localhost:3000 origin. The `secure: false` is needed because you are using http and not https.

Comment: I have tried that, it's not working @Gabe

Comment: Do you get the same or another error? Did you notice my mistake in the first edit, I put 3000 as target port, which must be 8080. I am getting tired, need to go to bed 